# Apache Trinidad Table - Can we disable navigation bar?

Tags: jsf, trinidad

How can we disable the navigation bar (select range result) of an Apache Trinidad's table component?

Comment: Why would you want to not display your whole collection? Maybe you should consider another component.

Comment: I have some problems when I change the range using the range navigation bar of trinidad table. More specifically, every time I change the range, the actions of command buttons included in other forms in the page, are not executed with the first click on them. Hence, I created my own navigation buttons to select the desired range and I want to disable the ones that trinidad table offers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to disable the navigation bar in a `tr:table` (that would defeat the purpose of the component), but you could do something like this:

In your backing bean, have 2 collections. The first would have all the elements and the second would have as many elements as the `rows` attribute. The `tr:table` is linked to the second collection. (`tr:table` navigation bar will never show) When you use your custom navigation buttons, you clear the 2nd collection and insert the right elements from the first collection into the second.

It's extra management, but I'm afraid it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide them using [skinning](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html).

Add a `styleClass` to your table, let's say `noControlBar`. Then put these lines in your skin to hide the control bar:

```
.noControlBar af|table::control-bar-top,
.noControlBar af|table::sub-control-bar { display: none; }
```